# Vuetify click on image slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to be able to click on a certain button inside a `v-img` component without triggering the event handler attached to the `v-img` itself. So far I have the following code

```
<div id="app">
  <v-container class="modal-container">
    <v-img
        lazy-src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/10/6"
        max-height="150"
        max-width="250"
        src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/500/300"
        @click="onClickImage"
    >
      <v-btn primary @click="onClickButton">open</v-btn>
    </v-img>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClickImage() {
      alert('Clicked image')
    },
    onClickButton() {
      alert('Clicked button')
    },
    
  }
})
```

when I click on the `open` button it triggers both `onClickImage` and `onClickButton` methods. I would like to trigger only `onClickButton` method. If this would be a native component I could do a simple `@click.self="onClickImage"` but since this is a Vuetify component I'm not sure how to handle the situation. Here is a playground with the code:

https://codepen.io/okokook/pen/GRZagxQ?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <v-btn primary @click.stop="onClickButton">open</v-btn>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers